# Is it possible to upload python list directly to firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have a list of python data that I need to get into my firebase , can I upload the entire list as one entity?

Comment: plz, add your code.

Comment: Asking questions with "is it possible" is very vague. So, the answer is "yes, it's possible" but without more information we cannot provide any details. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

very vauge question but the answer is yes by using

```
db.child(the_location_you_want).set(your_list)
```

Comment: Idk if this is what you want

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but with such a vague question, I would say it's best not to try to answer it until OP has clarified it.

Comment: okay i will keep that in mind next time i answer a question